# How to mark an email as seen after reading it with 'mark_seen = False' in imap_tools python?

Tags: python, imap, gmail-imap, imaplib, imap-tools

So first of all this is my code:

```
with MailBox('imap.gmail.com').login('username', 'password', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
                for msg in mailbox.fetch(AND(mark_seen=False, from_="some_domain")):
                    prt_msg_text = msg.text
                    if 'some_text' in prt_msg_text:
                        *here I want to mark the email as seen, if a specific text is in the msg*
```

So I want to read the email first without marking it as seen and if a specific condition is true, I want to mark this specific email as seen. Is that possible to do?

Comment: Just open it again?

Comment: I already tried that, by doing the following: 
msg(mark_seen=True), but I guess that's not how it works. As you can see its opening the messages in a loop, so Im not really sure how to open that specific message again.
I tried this: mailbox.fetch(msg) aswell, but that wasnt working either.

Comment: Following what?

Comment: sry, pressed enter to early^^

Comment: So how would I read that specific Email again? I thought about using the UID of the E-Mail, but Im really new to IMAP and Imap_tools so I didnt found an solution for that yet.

Comment: I replied to you

Answer (score 0):

I am new to it aswell, but I'm good at googling.

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, A

with MailBox('imap.gmail.com').login('username', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    uids = []
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(A(from_="@some.domain"), mark_seen=False):
        body = msg.text or msg.html
        if 'some_text' in body:
            uids.append(msg.uid)
    mailbox.flag(uids, imap_tools.MailMessageFlags.SEEN, True)
```

*mark_seen is fetch's argument.

Answer (score 0):

mark_seen is fetch's argument.

When you fix this error, use mark_seen arg and mailbox.flag method